# How to prevent AsyncSubject from completing when the last observer unsubscribes

Tags: javascript, rxjs

The `AsyncSubject` becomes observable when the last subject observer unsubscribes from the subject. Here is [the quote](https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339#2991):

> When it’s done, it’s done. Subjects cannot be reused after they’re
>   unsubscribed, completed or errored.

Here is the demo:

```
const ofObservable = Rx.Observable.of(1, 2, 3);
const subject = new Rx.AsyncSubject();

ofObservable.subscribe(subject);

subject.subscribe((v) => {
    console.log(v);
});

subject.unsubscribe((v) => {
    console.log(v);
});

// here I'll get the error "object unsubscribed"
subject.subscribe((v) => {
    console.log(v);
});
```

How to prevent the subject from completing?

There's a `share` operator:

> In RxJS 5, the operator `share()` makes a hot, refCounted observable
>   that can be retried on failure, or repeated on success. Because
>   subjects cannot be reused once they’ve errored, completed or otherwise
>   unsubscribed, the `share()` **operator will recycle dead subjects to
>   enable resubscription** to the resulting observable.

That is what I'm looking for. But `share` creates a subject and I need `AsyncSubject`.

Comment: [This test](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.4.2/spec/subjects/AsyncSubject-spec.ts#L125-L141) suggests it should be behaving the way you're expecting it to, does it not? Could something else be going on?

Comment: hmm, thanks, check [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/wFRWuiyWtsolP5CESdaA?p=preview), there's nothing else there

Comment: It looks kinda like a typo, to me. Assign the result of the `subject.subscribe` call to a variable (the result is a subscription) and call `unsubscribe` on the subscription - not the subject. With that change, the plunk seems to do what I'd expect it to.

Comment: @cartant, thanks, post it as an answer. I'm also wondering what happened when I unsubscribed the subject? It should already be unsubscribed from the `of` observable since the latter is completed, so what happens when I unsubscribe from the subject? Also, does it mean that the quote I referenced only applies to plain subjects?

Comment: I honestly don't know what was happening with the `unsubscribe` call made on the subject. It's kinda interesting, so I will look into it and will write up an answer later. Whether or not the quote in your question applies depends upon your definition of re-use, I guess. My understanding is that subscribers can subscribe to the async subject after it completes, but the async subject cannot be subscribed to another source observable.

Comment: okay, cool, looking forward to your answer)

Comment: Not clear to me what the question is, running the snipped above and don't see the 'object sunscribed' error either. If you need the share behaviour with an AsyncSubject, don't use share; use multicast on an async subject (or publishLast)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is down to this line:

```ts
subject.unsubscribe((v) => {
    console.log(v);
});
```

`Subject` [implements `ISubscription`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.4.2/src/Subject.ts#L22); which means it has an `unsubscribe` method and a `closed` property. Its [implementation of `unsubscribe`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.4.2/src/Subject.ts#L96-L100) is as follows:

```ts
unsubscribe() {
  this.isStopped = true;
  this.closed = true;
  this.observers = null;
}
```

Which is somewhat brutal. Essentially, it severs all communication with any subscribers to the subject without unsubscribing them. Similarly, it does not unsubscribe the subject itself from any observable it might happen to be subscribed to. (It also marks the subject as closed/stopped, which was the reason for your error.)

Given that it doesn't acutally perform any unsubscriptions, how it's supposed to be used is unclear. The description of [this test](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.4.2/spec/Subject-spec.ts#L235-L276):

```ts
it('should disallow new subscriber once subject has been disposed', () => {
```

suggests that it might be some sort of hangover from RxJS 4 - in which unsubscription was termed disposal.

Whatever the reason for its being, I would recommend never calling it. By way of example, look at this snippet:

```js
const source = Rx.Observable
  .interval(200)
  .take(5)
  .do(value => console.log(`source: ${value}`));

const subject = new Rx.Subject();
source.subscribe(subject);

const subscription = subject
  .switchMap(() => Rx.Observable
    .interval(200)
    .take(5)
    .delay(500))
  .subscribe(value => console.log(`subscription: ${value}`));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

It subscribes a subject to a source observable and then subscribes to an observable composed from the subject.

If `unsubscribe` is called on the subject, a couple of problems become evident:

- the subject's subscription to the source is not unsubscribed and an error is effected when the source attempts to call the subject's `next` method; and
- the subscription to the observable composed from the subject is not unsubscribed, so the `interval` observable within the `switchMap` keeps emitting after the `unsubscribe` call is made.

Try it out:

```js
const source = Rx.Observable
  .interval(200)
  .take(5)
  .do(value => console.log(`source: ${value}`));

const subject = new Rx.Subject();
source.subscribe(subject);

const subscription = subject
  .switchMap(() => Rx.Observable
    .interval(200)
    .take(5)
    .delay(500))
  .subscribe(value => console.log(`subscription: ${value}`));

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("subject.unsubscribe()");
  subject.unsubscribe();
}, 700);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

None of this seems like desirable behaviour, so calling `unsubscribe` on a `Subject` is something to be avoided.

Instead, the code in your snippet should unsubscribe using the `Subscription` returned by the `subscribe` call:

```ts
const subscription = subject.subscribe((v) => {
  console.log(v);
});
subscription.unsubscribe();
```

---

Subsequent to writing this answer, I've found the [following comment](https://medium.com/@benlesh/on-the-subject-of-subjects-in-rxjs-2b08b7198b93) from [Ben Lesh](http://stackoverflow.com/users/135786), that fits with my theory that it's related to the disposal of the subject:

> If you want the subject to loudly and angrily error when you `next` to it after it’s done being useful, you can call `unsubscribe` directly on the subject instance itself.