# re-subscribing a prevously unsubsribed Rx.Subject in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am not sure, if i am using a wrong approach or i just coding badly but to explanation of my problem.

I have a backend component, where i manage array of websockets ( because every websocket can have a different WS url, or they need to be turned off/on separately) and for every websocket, I want to know if its state and send it to a view trough Rx.Subject (if its opened, closed or if it dont have required data for making a connection)

which looks

```
public connectDeviceTerminalWebSocket(server: string, port: string): void {
    if (!(server !== null) && !(port !== null)) {

        let websocket: WebSocket = null;

        let wsPosition: number = this.hardwareTerminalwebSockets.findIndex(ws => {
            if (ws.url.includes(server + ':' + port)) {
                websocket = ws;
                return true;
            }
        });

        if (websocket) {
            this.closeHardwareTerminalWebsocket(websocket.url);
        }

        websocket = new WebSocket(`${this.wsProtocol}://${server}:${port}/${this.getToken()}`);

        websocket.addEventListener('close', ws => {
            this.reconnectTerminalWebSocketAfterTimeout();
            this.hardwareTerminalState.next({ 'websocketUrl': websocket.url, 'isConnected': false, 'reason': 'conectionFailed' });
        });

        websocket.addEventListener('open', ws => {
            this.reconnectTerminalWebSocketAfterTimeout();
            this.hardwareTerminalState.next({ 'websocketUrl': websocket.url, 'isConnected': true, 'reason': 'connected' });
        });


        let opened = Rx.Observable
            .fromEvent<void>(websocket, 'open');
        let channelReceived = Rx.Observable
            .fromEvent<MessageEvent>(websocket, 'message')
            .map(event => {
                try {
                    return JSON.parse(event.data);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.error('Parse error: ', e);
                }
                return null;
            });
        channelReceived
            .filter(message => message.message_channel === 'hardware-logger')
            .subscribe(this.hardwareTerminal);


        opened.subscribe(open => this.sendWebSocketTerminalMessageQueue());

        if (wsPosition > -1) {

            this.hardwareTerminalwebSockets[wsPosition] = websocket;
        } else {

            this.hardwareTerminalwebSockets.push(websocket);
        }
    } else {
        this.hardwareTerminalState.next({ websocketUrl: null, isConnected: null, 'reason': 'cantConnect' });
        return;
    }
}
```

and this works.

In my view, I have defined

```
hardwareTerminalStateWS: Rx.Subject<ITerminalWebsocketMessage>;
```

which i only subscribe once this way

```
this.hardwareTerminalStateWS.subscribe(msg => this.onStateMessage(msg));
```

and in ngOnDestroy in my view

```
this.hardwareTerminalWS.unsubscribe();
```

to unsubsribe it.

**Now the main problem** if i close/change to a different view, and go back (eg. re-opening and subscribing that again) it throws error

**"Error in ./hwcomponent class hwComponent - inline template:47:28 caused by: object unsubscribed"**

Should i change the Rx.Subject to a different class(Observer?)? Or use a different method to close hardwareTerminalStateWS?
Because if i dont close that, the next time i open view again, its open a second hardwareTerminalStateWS and read every messeage twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call `unsubscribe` on a `Subject` - instead of on a `Subscription` - you can no longer use the `Subject`.

For more information see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45112125/6680611) and Ben Lesh's Medium article [On The Subject Of Subjects](https://medium.com/@benlesh/on-the-subject-of-subjects-in-rxjs-2b08b7198b93):

> If you want the subject to loudly and angrily error when you `next` to it after it’s done being useful, you can call `unsubscribe` directly on the subject instance itself.

If you intend to reuse a subject, call `unsubscribe` on the `Subscription` (that is returned from the call to `subscribe`) instead.

Also, it should be noted that calling `unsubscribe` on the `Subject` will not have the same effect as calling `unsubscribe` on the `Subscription`. Typically, you would call `unsubscribe` on the `Subscription` and would also call `unsubscribe` on the `Subject` if you wanted to ensure it could not be reused.